# difference between user schema and acl schema in spring security?

Tags: authentication, spring-security, authorization, acl

In [this article](http://springinpractice.com/2010/07/06/spring-security-database-schemas-for-mysql/), 3 schema about spring security implementation are introduced. I want to know the differences between `user schema` and `acl schema`, which one is better to use, or in other words, I want to know the domain usage of each one, in order to choose the best solution for my application.

Comment: What do you mean by "schema"? What is a user schema?

Comment: this is a schema in spring security using a database. here is a reference:http://springinpractice.com/2010/07/06/spring-security-database-schemas-for-mysql/

Comment: can you describe your application first?

Comment: I have an application and it has its users. I want to know which one is better for me: ACL schema or user schema? these users should have their permissions for doing their tasks. for example one role have to issue a document another role has to approve that and another one has to do something else with that document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use ACL schema without User schema (because authentication process depends on User schema and normally you always need authentication). You have two options:

- User schema
- User schema & ACL schema

Let's see what they can do for you:

**User schema** is for authentication and authorisation based on **roles**. You can secure URL or method invocation. With User schema you can handle followig cases:

- A user with ADMIN role can acces to /admin.html.
- A user with PRODUCT_MANAGER role can acces to /add_product.html
- A user with PRODUCT_MANAGER role can acces to /manage_product.html?id=x.
- A user with PRODUCT_VIEWER role can acces to /view_product.html?id=x.

**ACL schema** is for enhanced authorisation. It will take in account actual domain object. You will be able handle following cases:

- A user with PRODUCT_MANAGER role can acces to /manage_product.html?id=136 **only if he is a owner of the product with id=136**.
- Some PRODUCT_MANAGER can give ability to manage his own product with id=136 to another PRODUCT_MANAGER.

So go on with User schema and add later ACL schema if you need it.